# Is it better to set global variables as instance variables in classes or not?

Tags: python

So i have a module called `config.py` which contains my global variables for a `pygame` tower defence game.

When i define a class in a different module, is it better to set those global variables to an instance variable of the same name or to just use `config.variable_name` whenever i need to use that global variable?

For example:

Setting the global variables to an instance variable in `__init__`:

```
self.map_height = config.map_height
self.map_width = config.map_width
```

Using them without the method above:

```
 for rw in range (config.map_height):
    for cl in range (config.map_width):
```

Comment: Just about anything the avoids using global variables will be "better".

Comment: I would pass config in to the class, then set `self.config = config` in `__init__` and go from there. Actual `global` variables are really horrible and bets avoided wherever possible.

Comment: I would avoid global variable whenever and wherever possible.

Comment: @match that won't help much over using the globals directly, the dependency on globals remains (and is less transparent), to make new instance really independent on possible future changes of the globals you may want to make a deepcopy of the config before assigning it to a instance variable

Comment: @lukas - I guess I should have split my comment in 2. The first part is that I wouldn't pass around 'parts' of config as it's less clear than passing all of it. The statement that globals were horrible wasn't meant to suggest that this first idea somehow replaced them - it was just a suggestion for improving this particular use case. (and yes, deepcopy is a good idea for avoiding global modification, since we're lacking trust constants).

Comment: @match Well i needed a way of centralising a set of variables that i could pass into multiple classes and i felt the best way of doing that was by creating a separate config file. The file contains certain constants such as colour values, screen size etc. that will not change. 

I know that global variables should be avoided at all costs and i tried to do so but i'm not sure how i can solve that situation with ease.